# Maven dependency resolution downgrades from compile to test; updateScopeCurrentPom

Tags: maven

In a simple setup of two Maven artifacts, I experienced an unexpected dependency resolution.

- artifact “mm-lib” depends on an external artifact “fluent-hc”
- artifact “mm-tool” depends on “mm-lib” and “fluent-hc”, but the latter only with scope “test”

I expected the “mm-tool” artifact to depend on “fluent-hc” with scope “compile”, since it depends on “mm-lib” and that in turn depends on “fluent-hc”.

What I actually got was that “mm-tool” depends on “external”, but only with scope “test”. I didn’t expect that.

I already did some research and ended up using this command:

```
 mvn dependency:tree -X -Dverbose | grep artifact=
```

The output of the command includes this line:

```
[DEBUG]   updateScopeCurrentPom:
    artifact=org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5:test,
    scopeIgnored=compile
```

This suggests to me that the behavior is intentional. But then, this means that I always have to check all dependencies of the main project whether they are really included, which feels weird to me.

Why is this behavior sensible, and do I really have to check all the dependencies manually?

---

For reference, here are the actual files. First, `mm-lib/pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>rillig</groupId>
  <artifactId>mm-lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then, `mm-tool/pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>rillig</groupId>
  <artifactId>mm-tool</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>rillig</groupId>
      <artifactId>mm-lib</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: test scope is not transitive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's sensible because you are manually specifying in `mmtool/pom.xml` that `fluent-hc` should have a scope of `test`.  So of course Maven assigns it a scope of test.  If you want `mmtool`'s `fluent-hc` dependency to inherit the scope from `mmlib`, then don't specify the `fluent-hc` dependency in `mmtool/pom.xml` at all.  Having it work the way you describe would make it so that you couldn't override scopes from transitive dependencies in your own POMs.